# Do Microsoft Windows/Office KB updates get 'rolled up' into future releases

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I recently implemented the solution described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23985778/9785102) stack exchange answer. I did not have to run the 'hotfix' or install the associated KB for the solution to solve my problem.

I have run a cmd systeminfo.exe to determine which KBs are installed on my machine, and the relevant KB is not this list (though the list *may* be truncated due to restricted privileges - it has only 4 items).

I suspect that historic KBs are incorporated (where relevant) into future software releases, and therefore a KB released in 2014 would now be part of the Windows/Office standard. Is that the case? The rest of the internet has not yet yielded the answer to me. Maybe I'm searching using the wrong terms.

More generally - are all relevant KBs released for previous versions of Microsoft software incorporated into current/future releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*are all relevant KBs released for previous versions of Microsoft software incorporated into current/future releases?*

Yes, all Office and Windows updates incorporate all the latest updates. It has been this way for a long while.

More information: Try the following Microsoft Articles:

(1) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/servicing-stack-updates#:~:targetText=Both%20Windows%2010%20and%20Windows,fixes%20from%20all%20previous%20updates and

(2) https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/824684/description-of-the-standard-terminology-that-is-used-to-describe-micro

From the second article, quote "The Monthly Rollup is product specific, addresses both new security issues and nonsecurity issues in a single update and will proactively include updates that were released in the past."

Comment: Thank you for providing and answer. I there a way I would have been able to find this out easily, without asking here?

Comment: Microsoft has been rolling up updates for quite a while so you can probably find numerous articles but it is just common practice now

Comment: I have tried to find articles, but I couldn't and still can't. Otherwise I wouldn't have had to ask the question. I suspect (and hope) that is because I don't know enough about the subject to enter the correct terms into a google search. While I don't doubt what you're saying, it would add a lot to your answer if you could substantiate it with a link. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Try the following Microsoft Articles:  (1) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/servicing-stack-updates#:~:targetText=Both%20Windows%2010%20and%20Windows,fixes%20from%20all%20previous%20updates. and (2) https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/824684/description-of-the-standard-terminology-that-is-used-to-describe-micro  . From the second article, quote "The Monthly Rollup is product specific, addresses both new security issues and nonsecurity issues in a single update and will proactively include updates that were released in the past."

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include the above information

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome and good luck with this